# max interval of definition of a Cauchy problem's solution

Tags: real-analysis

I have this Cauchy problem : $x(x-1)y'=e^{-y}$ with initial condition $y(2)=\log a,a>0$.
I have find the solution :$y(x)=\log(a+\log\frac{2(x-1)}{x})$
But how can I find the max interval of definition?

Answer (score 1):

It will be the largest interval around $2$ on which $y$ is defined. Since the logarithm is defined only for positive numbers, there are two conditions:
$$\frac{2(x-1)}{x}>0,\quad a+\log\frac{2(x-1)}{x}>0.$$

Comment: Is $(1+\frac{1}{2e^a-1},+\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.